# how to convert this simple sql query to doctrine querybuilder

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I'm using php doctrine, and i can't convert this sql query to querybuilder . 
i have problems with "group by"
any help please ?

> SELECT * FROM message WHERE sender_id='2' OR receiver_id = '2' Group By (if(sender_id > receiver_id, sender_id, receiver_id)) , (if(sender_id <= receiver_id, sender_id,receiver_id)) Order BY createdAt DESC

this is what i did but i need condition on groupby

```
  $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('m');
  $queryBuilder->where('m.sender = :user or m.receiver =:user')
  ->groupBy('m.sender','m.receiver')
  ->orderBy('m.createdAt', 'Desc')
  ->setParameter('user', $user);
```

Comment: Save yourself the headache and just write straight queries.

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m');
$qb->where($qb->expr()->orX(
    $qb->expr()->eq('m.sender', ':user'),
    $qb->expr()->eq('m.receiver', ':user')
))->groupBy('m.sender')
->addGroupBy('m.receiver')
->orderBy('m.createdAt', 'DESC')
->setParameter('user', $user);
```

So apart from factoring out your where statement into relevant `expr()` statements ([documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class)) the only other change is splitting your `groupBy` into `groupBy` and then `addGroupBy`. You can do the same if you ever need to order by more than one things (`orderBy` and `addOrderBy`).

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work well for me , because i want to show the last message between user1 and user2 no matter if user1 was sender or receiver